# Multiple boxplots in R while grouping a matrix both by columns and rows

Tags: r, boxplot

I am having trouble trying to figure out how to make a single figure containing multiple boxplots in R, while grouping my data frame/ matrix both by columns and rows.

I have a data frame in R with 10 rows and 500 columns. The columns are separated into 2 groups(factors -  1's and 2's) and now I want to have a single figure containing two boxplots for each row of my data frame subject to the column groups.

Ex.

```
    M1 N2 O1 P2 Q1 R2      # [The 1's and 2's refer to my two column groups]
 A  10 11 12 13 14 15
 B  15 14 13 12 11 10 
 C  20 21 22 23 24 25
 D  25 24 23 22 21 20
```

So for the above example I would like to have a single figure with "4 boxplots pairs" for each row such that each boxplot pair will represent values corresponding to 1's and 2's factors of my column.

Thanks in Advance !!!

Comment: can you add an example of your expected output?

Comment: Sorry not enough "reputation" to add a figure :-) !!! But as I said I need each row to be plotted as pairs of boxplot based on the column factors ( 1's and 2's)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here on idea using `reshape2`. Since You have more columns than rows, it natural to work on the transpose.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
dt <- read.table(text='
M1 N2 O1 P2 Q1 R2     
A  10 11 12 13 14 15
B  15 14 13 12 11 10 
C  20 21 22 23 24 25
D  25 24 23 22 21 20',header=TRUE)
dt.m <- melt(t(dt))
dt.m$Var1 <- gsub('[A-Z]','',dt.m$Var1)
```

Here 2 options to plot :

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
p1 <- ggplot(dt.m) +
   geom_boxplot(aes(x=Var2,y=value,fill=Var1))

p2 <- ggplot(dt.m) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(x=Var2,y=value,fill=Var2))+
  facet_grid(~Var1)

grid.arrange(p1,p2)
```

[image]